# Execute a method whenever some method has finished executing completely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a javascript method defined as follows:

```
updtCrtEdtPage = function() {PrimeFaces.ab({source:'j_id_ev',formId:'j_id_es',process:'typeNewLOB_in lobIdForEdit j_id_ev',update:'createLOBFullPagePanel',oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){prepareForCrtEdtFullPage();},params:arguments[0]});}
```

I want to **execute certain method (*afterComplete()*) whenever this method has finished executing**. (This method actually initiates an ajax request & appends the received HTML data on the DOM). So I want my *afterComplete()* method to be executed whenever ajax response has been  received.

I cannot directly do like:

```
updtCrtEdtPage();
afterComplete();
```

as this would call the afterComplete() soon after ajax request is initiated & not completely finished executing yet.

Is there any JS/ jQuery way I could do that ?

Comment: you can call in oncomplete

Comment: @hr_117: Because I would like to specify the method for after execution while calling the method & not while defining. Becasue it varies for every call to this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass `afterComplete` as a parameter so your function can call it when the ajax call is complete.  Something like this...

```
updtCrtEdtPage = function(callback) {
    PrimeFaces.ab({
        source:'j_id_ev',
        formId:'j_id_es',
        process:'typeNewLOB_in lobIdForEdit j_id_ev',
        update:'createLOBFullPagePanel',
        oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){
            prepareForCrtEdtFullPage();
            callback();
        },
        params:arguments[0]
    });
}

updtCrtEdtPage(afterComplete);
```

Since you say you can't modify `updtCrtEdtPage`, but you can modify `prepareForCrtEdtFullPage` I'd suggest using a global variable to determine which callback function to call when the method is complete...

```
updtCrtEdtPageCallback = afterComplete;
```

and then in `prepareForCrtEdtFullPage` just add the last line...

```
updtCrtEdtPageCallback();
```

The first method is tidier, but the second will suffice for your particular situation.

Comment: I know about this but actually I would like to specify the  method for after exectution while calling the method & not while defining. Becasue it varies for every call to this method.

Comment: That's exactly what this does.  You can call `updtCrtEdtPage(anyCallbackMethod)` with the above code

Comment: Thanks but i forgot to tell you one more thing I do not have *full* control over the definition of `updtCrtEdtPage`  method as this is framework generated. So I cant add a parameter to method defintion but What I can do is to specify method in oncomplete section of the definition but then how do I make that a custom method!?

Comment: You could use a global variable - `updtCrtEdtPageCallback` for example - and just call that at the end of `prepareForCrtEdtFullPage()`  Then you would just say `updtCrtEdtPageCallback = afterComplete`

Comment: Modified answer to include the extra info.

Answer (score 0):

your updtCrtEdtPage = function() has an oncomplete callback which is called when the ajax response has been received, add your afterComplete function in that callback and it will execute after the ajax request has been completed.

```
 oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){
   prepareForCrtEdtFullPage();
   afterComplete()
 }
```